# converting randomly generate string instances to datetime mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, casting

I want to update a table (cust_id date_id) with randomly generated content

for the cust_id I am using

```
     rand()*1000
```

for the datetime I am generating random dates over the past three years as follows

```
   CONCAT(ROUND(RAND()*-3) + YEAR(NOW()),"-",ROUND(RAND()*11) + 1,"-",ROUND(RAND()*27) + 1)
```

Then I am generating many instances by creating inner joins from a table with 10 numbers

```
   FROM numbers JOIN number n2 JOIN number  n3
```

Putting it all together I run

```
   INSERT INTO orders (cust_id, date_id)
   SELECT ROUND(RAND()*1000) AS cust_id,
   CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONCAT(ROUND(RAND()*-3) + YEAR(NOW()),"-",ROUND(RAND()*11) + 1,"- 
    ",ROUND(RAND()*27) + 1))) AS date_id
   FROM numbers JOIN number n2 JOIN number  n3 JOIN;
```

I have played around with different conversion formats, and tried to set the result to a variable and cast that to datetime but it is all throwing up errors. I suspect that the problem is that mysql is reading it as a function rather than a string. I have found another work around where I keep the original datetime and use intervals, but would like to know what the issue with my initial approach is. Any insights that people have would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not start with the problem and an example of a satisfactory solution. To that end, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have your basic formula working using the DATE() function.

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(ROUND(RAND()*-3) + YEAR(NOW()),"-",
                   ROUND(RAND()*11) + 1,"-",
                   ROUND(RAND()*27) + 1))
```

Still, you're much better off using

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL ROUND(RAND()*3*365.25) DAY
```

Why? If you leave leap-year February 29 out of your test data, you leave out something critical to test.  And if you leave out days 29, 30, and 31 from all your test months, you may not get test coverage for end-of-month date arithmetic.